# Hibernate SessionFactory through Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am using Hibernate3 with Spring 3. I am trying to start hibernate transaction using Spring.
Given below is my configurations

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I am getting the following error while running the application.

```
HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:341)
```

I have the following line in hibernate config xml

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

The code which uses hibernate transaction is:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Book book = (Book)session.get(Book.class, id);
```

What could be wrong in this? Is the value for current_session_context_class is anything other than thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the line

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

It seems, When you are using Spring transaction management, you need to use the sessionFactory which you configured in the applicationContext.xml (using dependency injection).

Following piece of code solved the problem.

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
   this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

In the applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="BookService" class="hibernate.BookServiceImpl">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```